# Spring security login for external links

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am developing a web application and I have integrated spring security for authentication. I am using the default login page of spring. There are external links present for my application from other applications and in some documents. I have written controllers for these links to show the required data to the user after successful login. My problem is that when I access the links from other applications or documents I am taken to the login page (which is expected if the user is not logged in) and then I am redirected to home page of the application insted of previously requested URL. This happens all the time when I access from those links and asks for login even if the session is active and then then taken to home page after that. Where as if the URL is copied and pasted in the same browser it works fine. What could be the reason for this to happen?

Here is my spring config file

```
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_EDIT,ROLE_VIEW" />
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/">
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
       <!--my custom authentication-->
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler.  Something like this

```
<http auto-config="true">
<http-basic  />
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</http>
```

Inside customAuthenticationSuccessHandler you can override onAuthenticationSuccess method and write your own code for identifying the request URL and redirecting accordingly to the same if it is from external app.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication
            .getPrincipal();
    // CODE TO IDENTIFY THE REQUEST URL AND REDIRECT TO SAME IF IT IS EXTERNAL URL(FROM OTHER APP). 
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, targetUrl);

}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and the url which I get from the request is "app root"/login , Im unable to get the previously requested url with this method.

Comment: You can try appending a parameter in request such as clientId which will be specific to the application from where the request is coming. Also in your application maintain a map of each clientId  with a specific redirectURL. In the handler then set the redirectURL as per the clientID u get